# What IPv6 CPE is available?

Tags: router, ipv6

I was wondering what CPE (customer-premises equipment) had proper IPv6 support.  I'm in the process of getting an AS and some IPv4 addressing (yes, **I**'m depleting IPv4.  Sorry, folks) and I was intending to future-proof a bit by getting a /48 and getting IPv6 working properly.

If I were to set it up at our end, what CPE could I recommend to my users so they could use IPv6 end-to-end.  Ideally, I'd be looking at a router with 802.11n support, that does DHCPv6 and/or NDP/SLAAC and also has a firewall with the default configuration being allow from the secured network to the insecure network and deny in the opposite direction (ie the equivalent of the usual IPv4 configuration, but with the NAT taken out).  Also, it should probably also be able to terminate a 6to4 tunnel to SixXS or Hurricane Electric and be easy for a relative novice to set up.

I hear that the Apple AirPort Extreme is a good IPv6 option.  Is that correct?  What other manufacturers have something available now?

Comment: You'll probably get a /56 actually - what network interface are you after? DSL or just ethernet, if the latter what speed? I'm looking at the Cisco 800 range for you and would like to narrow it down for you - here's a link, they all do IPv6 - http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps380/prod_models_comparison.html

Comment: I expect we're mostly looking at DSL - Virgin Media (cableco in the UK) don't support IPv6, so it's all DSL stuff.  I was rather hoping for less than £500 per user, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have xs4all adsl in the Netherlands which offer native IPv6 over PPPoA (adsl) / PPPoE (vdsl). As CPE to work with this they name [on their IPv6 site](http://www.xs4all.nl/klant/helpdesk/internet/ipv6/) (in Dutch):

- AVM FRITZ!Box 7340 internationaal
- AVM FRITZ!box 7270 internationaal
- AVM FRITZ!box 7570 internationaal

Needing 'labor' firmwares

- Draytek Vigor 2130n icm Vigor 120

Needing updated firmware

- Cisco 876/877 (release 12.4T)
- Cisco 886/887 (release 12.4T)

Needing firmware with the right licenses

(all research by the great guys at xs4all)

If you're in the UK, talk to your counterparts at AAISP.

Comment: I'm going to try the Fritz!box, as the Draytek is not DSL, and the Ciscos are about five times the price.  I'll let people know how I get on with this and AAISP.

Comment: Just to let people know, I was upgraded to FTTC at home, which comes with a VDSL modem from BT OpenReach here. I have a Draytek Vigor 2130n and IPv6 is working on that really well.  I still don't have my PI /48 at work, so that will happen eventually, I hope!

Answer (score 2):

RIPE have a [very useful page](http://labs.ripe.net/Members/mirjam/ipv6-cpe-survey-updated-september-2010) listing CPE support for IPv6.  This is for CPE available within the RIPE region, ie in Europe.

There's [also a page](http://labs.ripe.net/Members/mirjam/ipv6-cpe-surveys) that should have links to the latest survey.

These not only list what devices support IPv6, but have a matrix of precisely what IPv6 features they support.